# $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \lfloor2x\rfloor\cdot x}{ \lfloor2x\rfloor+x^2} \ dx $

Tags: integration, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[image]

I need help to know if I worked the example correctly or incorrectly

Comment: And what did you do, then?

Comment: Show us your try!

Comment: [x]=x-{x},  0<{x}<=1,

Comment: answer: ln(8/5)/2 (B)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x\lfloor 2 x\rfloor }{x^2+ \lfloor 2 x\rfloor } \, dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{8}{5}\right)$$

Because the floor of $2x$ is $0$ between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$.

$$...$$

[image]